# How to pass a script to adb so the shell dosen't shut down after it

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, adb

i'm accessing very often a database file in my android device.

I have to do the following each time:

```
~/development/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

then in the shell i have to copy and paste the following command

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.myco.myapp/databases/mydb.db
```

I've found that i can call both lines like this :

```
 ~/development/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.myco.myapp/databases/mydb.db"
```

But after the execution of the sqlite instruction i lose controll over the shell since the script has been executed and it's over,

How can I access the database in a single command ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your SQL query as a parameter for `sqlite3` - just add it to your command after the dababase file path

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.myco.myapp/databases/mydb.db "select name, value from tablename;"
```